# Download photos from ULSs in a CSV file – urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib, http-status-code-403

My script below is supposed to download a bunch of images from a list of URLs but it keeps hitting this error `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error from `raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Not sure what to do. You can run it yourself, I provided everything below.

Any help would be very appreciated (:

The goal is to download a bunch of images from a list of URLs in a CSV without hitting Error 403

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import urllib.request
import requests
import praw
import csv

r = praw.Reddit(client_id=client_id,
                client_secret=client_secret, 
                user_agent=user_agent,
                username=username,
                password=password)

subred = r.subreddit("partyparrot")
top = subred.top(limit = 780)
type(top)
x = next(top)
dir(x)

with open("output_reddit.csv", 'r') as csvfile:

    headers = {
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
                }

    for line in csvfile:
        splitted_line = line.split('||')
        if splitted_line[2] != '' and splitted_line[2] != "\n" and ".png" in splitted_line[2]:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[2], filename=("img_" + splitted_line[0] + ".png")) 
            print ("Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))

        elif splitted_line[2] != '' and splitted_line[2] != "\n" and ".jpg" in splitted_line[2]:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[2], filename=("img_" + splitted_line[0] + ".jpg")) 
            print ("Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))

        elif splitted_line[2] != '' and splitted_line[2] != "\n" and "v.redd.it" in splitted_line[2]:

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[2].rstrip() + "/DASH_720.mp4", filename=("img_" + splitted_line[0] + ".mp4")) 
            print ("Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))

        else:
            print ("No result for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))
```

---

Below is the `output_reddit.csv` file for reference.

```
2||I tried the no pet challenge... she wasn't having it||https://v.redd.it/da60x1qizgs51
3||My trip to the salon went horribly wrong.||https://v.redd.it/tfzc1vye6ds51
4||A few sketches of my macaw buddy from work. Haven't seen this silly girl in six months due to quarantine, I miss her.||https://i.redd.it/jjkb3b5ntis51.jpg
5||Thermals of the party girl!||https://i.imgur.com/rfGChUQ.jpg
6||I present you with Lorena. After rescue, I found out shes an old bird and mostly blind. Once allowed out of her cage to roam free and was given plenty of wonderful fruits and veggies, she became very warm and cuddly. Shes a very sweet regal lady and definitely a queen.||https://v.redd.it/saojuaycnds51
7||A day in the life of the OG Party Parrot. Credit: Ranger Sarah Little.||https://i.redd.it/wjwvl3u01js51.jpg
8||Party game||https://v.redd.it/8myoampepgs51
9||Here I present to you the Christmas loving partyparrot named Felix. He loved sitting in the tree but never chewed on it. Now rest in peace, little friend we will allways love and remember you.||https://i.redd.it/wengcned7is51.jpg
```

---

Below is the full log for reference as well.

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Download matt$ python run.py
Image saved for 2
Image saved for 3
Image saved for 4
Image saved for 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 107, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[2].rstrip() + "/DASH_720.mp4", filename=("img_" + splitted_line[0] + ".mp4")) 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Could you provide one url from the list? So that it would be easier for testing.

Comment: @Sushil I added it above as "output_reddit.csv" and I reference the URL as `splitted_line[2]` in the script

Comment: I tried it out with one image and it worked. Check out my edit

Comment: Did you try to check what URL is actually being accessed? Do you understand what the error message means? Can you take one of the URLs that didn't work, and try it in a web browser?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes the URLs are above so you can also view them. It links to the actual source of the image or video and Error 403 means the requested URL is forbidden, mostly a client related issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. It might be a header problem

Comment: I mean, make the program output the result of `splitted_line[2].rstrip() + "/DASH_720.mp4"` and test the non-working result in a browser specifically.

Comment: For example, the URL `https://v.redd.it/saojuaycnds51/DASH_720.mp4` did not work for me in a browser.

Comment: The corresponding post worked fine, and so did other video URLs in your sample. So I guess the issue is on Reddit's end.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Your comments inspired me to `try except` the broken URLs, it worked! So thank you, read my answer to this post

Comment: I think it may still be worth posting somewhere on Reddit to ask them what's going on. I was unable to find a simple explanation.